RBAC system that lets you pick what role you want to log into?
I'm working with a system that asks you to select which role you want to use when you log in. Is there a name for this approach? (The other RBAC systems I've worked with simply give the user the union of permissions of all their roles.)

That is still RBAC, but you're only assigning one role to the user.
